# Can't access localhost on a VM Windows Server 2012 Azure

Tags: windows-server-2012, virtual-machines, azure, localhost

Hi I'm new to VM Technology. I have a Microsoft Bizspark Account with Azure on it. I created a Virtual Machine, Windows Server 2012 and installed Xampp on it. Yeah I know it would be better to use IIS but I want to use Xampp. I will use PHP. So basically I installed Xampp and the Web Server is Running. I tried to access the VM's localhost on other computer or my computer via Public IP of the VM and I can't access the VM's localhost. Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What IP is it resolving to? Is Apache bound to it? Is the firewall interfering?

Answer (score 0):

you need to open up the endpoint on your VM first and then use the CloudService Name to access the WebSite hosted on your machine. Localhost won't work but on the VM itself. If you did'nt create the VM in a Vnet you can also try to address the VM'sPublic ip and put that in your hosts folder to easily conenct (but that's a very bad practice :-) )